# Trying to edit and change target framework in *.csproj file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, intellisense

I have a project which was in asp.net MVC 4.0, Now I updated my project MVC version from 4.0 to 5.2.
After this update, I have lost my IntelliSense from all my `*.cshtml` files, that's OK still I can work without IntelliSense but suddenly I don't know what happened with my project all the `*.cshtml` files in a project are not opening.
Below message is showing when I trying to open the *.cshtml file.
[image]

I think there is an issue with my .csproj file, In that file the target framework is still is 4.0

[image]

Can anybody suggest do I really need to update .csproj file for open the *.cshtml pages and enable the IntelliSense ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Close VS, delete .suo file, open again. That should fix it

Comment: No I have tried this but not solved, it solved by changing target framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the target framework. If you are using 4.0 try to make it 4.5.